# Why is === operator not working properly?

Tags: javascript

When I am running the following code, it returns true

```
parseFloat(0.5*2)===parseInt(0.5*2)
```

However when I run the following code, it correctly returns false.

```
parseFloat(0.5*0.5) === parseInt(0.5*0.5)
```

Should it not be false for both case? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you look at what the values you're comparing are?

Comment: Why would you think the second should be false? I don't get why you are confused?

Comment: Maybe you seem to think that there are two types of numbers in javascript? ("float" and "int"). Javascript only has one "number" base type. So, since the numbers are equal in the first case (`1.0`), the triple equality (type + value equality) holds.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has attracted downvotes. Maybe I'd suggest to confirm and add to the question the  _reason_ that makes you think the first equality should be `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should it not be false for both case? Or am I missing something?

Maybe you think that there are two different "float" and "int" types of numbers in JavaScript, and therefore the triple-equality should check for type and return `false`?

In JavaScript `1` and `2.3` are the same type "number".

So, since the numbers are equal in the first case (1.0), the triple equality (type + value equality) holds.

Check it with literal values:

```js
console.log(1 === 1.0)
```